# ES6 Import inside of Android Webview - not a constructor error

Tags: javascript, android, ecmascript-6, webview, three.js

I am rendering an html webpage inside of a WebView which uses three.js to render a 3D model. Thus far all of that is working fine. I am now attempting to add touch/drag controls to move the camera around. I found some example code to make this work and I've implemented it. Here are the relevant portions code:

```
import * as tc from './TrackballControls.js';
//....
controls = new tc.TrackballControls( camera , renderer.domElement);
controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
```

On PC in Crome and Firefox everything works perfectly, my model renders and dragging does change the camera view. In Chrome and Firefox on my Android device loading the page via local network everything also works fine.

However in the WebView within my application I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: tc.TrackballControls is not a constructor
```

It seems that creating the TrackballControls object is failing. Why does it fail in this way inside of the WebView and not in Chrome on the same phone?

This is my html app directory structure:

[image]

I have edited three.module.js and TrackballControls.js to account for them being in the same directory like this:

```
// in index.html js:
import * as THREE from './three.module.js';
import * as tc from './TrackballControls.js';    

// in TrackballControls.js:
import {
  EventDispatcher,
  MOUSE,
  Quaternion,
  Vector2,
  Vector3
} from "./three.module.js";
```

Is there anything I can alter in the html/javascript or Android java code to make it work correctly inside the WebView?

I have tried on 2 different devices, their webview userAgent strings are:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; S60 Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/79.0.3945.93 Mobile Safari/537.36", source: https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/www/cpb_3d_model_wgt/index.html (27)
```

and

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; LM-V405 Build/OPM1.171019.026; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/79.0.3945.93 Mobile Safari/537.36", source: https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/www/cpb_3d_model_wgt/index.html (27)
```

**EDIT** a bit more info:
I was trying to serve my page out of the Assets directory using this:

```
final WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader = new WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
            .addPathHandler("/assets/", new WebViewAssetLoader.AssetsPathHandler(this))
            .addPathHandler("/res/", new WebViewAssetLoader.ResourcesPathHandler(this))
            .build();

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                                          WebResourceRequest request) {
           if (!request.isForMainFrame() && request.getUrl().getPath().endsWith(".js")) {
                Log.d(TAG, " js file request need to set mime/type " + request.getUrl().getPath());
               try {
                   return new WebResourceResponse("application/javascript", null, new BufferedInputStream(view.getContext().getAssets().open("www/cpb_3d_model_wgt/three.module.js")));
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
            return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.getUrl());
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            //Log.d(TAG, "error: " + error.getDescription());
            Log.d(TAG, "error: " + request.getUrl());
        }
    });

    wv.loadUrl("https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/www/cpb_3d_model_wgt/index.html");
```

With my page served this way I get the `not a constructor` error. I've used chrome remote device inspector to look at the network request for the TrackballControl.js file and I see this:

[image: response headers screenshot]

and when the same page is served from my PC using python web server everything works fine (no errors and all functionality works) these are the response headers:

[image: successful response headers screenshot]

As far as I can tell something about the response or headers is causing some issue with importing which is making the code fail because the imported constructor function isn't getting to exist properly.

Once I noticed this difference in the response headers I ditched the `WebViewAssetLoader` and starting serving my page with NanoHTTPD and when it's served that way everything works as expected.

**Another EDIT:** Looking back at my Asset Loader / intercept request code now I can see that I have hard coded the "wrong" js file to get returned for every request that ends with .js which is very likely the reason for the "not a constructor error" My mistake, and I should have included that code when I originally posted the question but I overlooked it.

Comment: What version of the Android WebView? (navigator.userAgent)

Comment: Also note that unless you modified the source you need to keep the structure of three.js repo to use `import`. That means `three.module.js` needs to be in `somefolder/build` and `TrackballControls.js` needs to be in `somefolder/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js` because inside it references `three.module.js` at `../../../build/three.module.js` (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/0abe06ef133b8ad38ba2e6c619a116d30de5c588/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js#L14)

Comment: I did modify the files to us js files in the root of a dir in my assets. I will post the dir structure and version from user agent tomorrow

Comment: @gman I've added the userAgent strings and some more details about my directory structure and js file modifications.

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the application that shows the WebView?

Comment: What is the configuration settings for the webview?  in android , the webview is hardly configured, with respect to the other browsing apps, and you need to configure it manually. 
For example you also need to enable javascript for the webview (maybe it's obvious, but you didn't mention anything about it).

Comment: @Juan I do have javascript on the webview enabled.

Answer (score 2):

TrackballControls.js wasn't written as a module that you can import. Instead, it assumes the `THREE` variable is globally available, and it appends it to `THREE`. To fix this, you might need to copy-and paste its [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js) into your own file (let's call it `TC.js`) and make some alterations at the beginning and at the end:

#### TC.js:

```
// 1. Import THREE instead of assuming it's globally available
import * as THREE from './three.module.js';

// 2a. Remove "THREE." and make it a stand-alone variable
var TrackballControls = function ( object, domElement ) {

    // ... All 600+ lines of internal content stays the same

};

// 2a. Remove "THREE." at the bottom of the file as well
TrackballControls.prototype = Object.create( THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype );
TrackballControls.prototype.constructor = TrackballControls;

// 3. Export the object to be used in other files
export default TrackballControls;
```

Now you should be able to use your own `TC.js` file in your project:

#### main.js:

```
import * as THREE from './three.module.js';
import TrackballControls from 'TC.js';

const controls = new TrackballControls(camera , renderer.domElement);
```

I made an example below to demonstrate how copy-pasting `TrackballControls` can still work by making it a stand-alone variable The top 600+ lines are literally copy-pasted, with the modifications I mentioned above. The rest of the scene setup is at the end of the JS:

```js
// In your code, you'd import THREE here, instead of via <script> tag
// import * as THREE from 'three';

const TrackballControls = function ( object, domElement ) {

 if ( domElement === undefined ) console.warn( 'THREE.TrackballControls: The second parameter "domElement" is now mandatory.' );
 if ( domElement === document ) console.error( 'THREE.TrackballControls: "document" should not be used as the target "domElement". Please use "renderer.domElement" instead.' );

 var _this = this;
 var STATE = { NONE: - 1, ROTATE: 0, ZOOM: 1, PAN: 2, TOUCH_ROTATE: 3, TOUCH_ZOOM_PAN: 4 };

 this.object = object;
 this.domElement = domElement;

 // API

 this.enabled = true;

 this.screen = { left: 0, top: 0, width: 0, height: 0 };

 this.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
 this.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
 this.panSpeed = 0.3;

 this.noRotate = false;
 this.noZoom = false;
 this.noPan = false;

 this.staticMoving = false;
 this.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.2;

 this.minDistance = 0;
 this.maxDistance = Infinity;

 this.keys = [ 65 /*A*/, 83 /*S*/, 68 /*D*/ ];

 this.mouseButtons = { LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE, MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.ZOOM, RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN };

 // internals

 this.target = new THREE.Vector3();

 var EPS = 0.000001;

 var lastPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
 var lastZoom = 1;

 var _state = STATE.NONE,
  _keyState = STATE.NONE,

  _eye = new THREE.Vector3(),

  _movePrev = new THREE.Vector2(),
  _moveCurr = new THREE.Vector2(),

  _lastAxis = new THREE.Vector3(),
  _lastAngle = 0,

  _zoomStart = new THREE.Vector2(),
  _zoomEnd = new THREE.Vector2(),

  _touchZoomDistanceStart = 0,
  _touchZoomDistanceEnd = 0,

  _panStart = new THREE.Vector2(),
  _panEnd = new THREE.Vector2();

 // for reset

 this.target0 = this.target.clone();
 this.position0 = this.object.position.clone();
 this.up0 = this.object.up.clone();
 this.zoom0 = this.object.zoom;

 // events

 var changeEvent = { type: 'change' };
 var startEvent = { type: 'start' };
 var endEvent = { type: 'end' };


 // methods

 this.handleResize = function () {

  var box = this.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  // adjustments come from similar code in the jquery offset() function
  var d = this.domElement.ownerDocument.documentElement;
  this.screen.left = box.left + window.pageXOffset - d.clientLeft;
  this.screen.top = box.top + window.pageYOffset - d.clientTop;
  this.screen.width = box.width;
  this.screen.height = box.height;

 };

 var getMouseOnScreen = ( function () {

  var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

  return function getMouseOnScreen( pageX, pageY ) {

   vector.set(
    ( pageX - _this.screen.left ) / _this.screen.width,
    ( pageY - _this.screen.top ) / _this.screen.height
   );

   return vector;

  };

 }() );

 var getMouseOnCircle = ( function () {

  var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

  return function getMouseOnCircle( pageX, pageY ) {

   vector.set(
    ( ( pageX - _this.screen.width * 0.5 - _this.screen.left ) / ( _this.screen.width * 0.5 ) ),
    ( ( _this.screen.height + 2 * ( _this.screen.top - pageY ) ) / _this.screen.width ) // screen.width intentional
   );

   return vector;

  };

 }() );

 this.rotateCamera = ( function () {

  var axis = new THREE.Vector3(),
   quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(),
   eyeDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
   objectUpDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
   objectSidewaysDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
   moveDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
   angle;

  return function rotateCamera() {

   moveDirection.set( _moveCurr.x - _movePrev.x, _moveCurr.y - _movePrev.y, 0 );
   angle = moveDirection.length();

   if ( angle ) {

    _eye.copy( _this.object.position ).sub( _this.target );

    eyeDirection.copy( _eye ).normalize();
    objectUpDirection.copy( _this.object.up ).normalize();
    objectSidewaysDirection.crossVectors( objectUpDirection, eyeDirection ).normalize();

    objectUpDirection.setLength( _moveCurr.y - _movePrev.y );
    objectSidewaysDirection.setLength( _moveCurr.x - _movePrev.x );

    moveDirection.copy( objectUpDirection.add( objectSidewaysDirection ) );

    axis.crossVectors( moveDirection, _eye ).normalize();

    angle *= _this.rotateSpeed;
    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, angle );

    _eye.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
    _this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

    _lastAxis.copy( axis );
    _lastAngle = angle;

   } else if ( ! _this.staticMoving && _lastAngle ) {

    _lastAngle *= Math.sqrt( 1.0 - _this.dynamicDampingFactor );
    _eye.copy( _this.object.position ).sub( _this.target );
    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( _lastAxis, _lastAngle );
    _eye.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
    _this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

   }

   _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );

  };

 }() );


 this.zoomCamera = function () {

  var factor;

  if ( _state === STATE.TOUCH_ZOOM_PAN ) {

   factor = _touchZoomDistanceStart / _touchZoomDistanceEnd;
   _touchZoomDistanceStart = _touchZoomDistanceEnd;

   if ( _this.object.isPerspectiveCamera ) {

    _eye.multiplyScalar( factor );

   } else if ( _this.object.isOrthographicCamera ) {

    _this.object.zoom *= factor;
    _this.object.updateProjectionMatrix();

   } else {

    console.warn( 'THREE.TrackballControls: Unsupported camera type' );

   }

  } else {

   factor = 1.0 + ( _zoomEnd.y - _zoomStart.y ) * _this.zoomSpeed;

   if ( factor !== 1.0 && factor > 0.0 ) {

    if ( _this.object.isPerspectiveCamera ) {

     _eye.multiplyScalar( factor );

    } else if ( _this.object.isOrthographicCamera ) {

     _this.object.zoom /= factor;
     _this.object.updateProjectionMatrix();

    } else {

     console.warn( 'THREE.TrackballControls: Unsupported camera type' );

    }

   }

   if ( _this.staticMoving ) {

    _zoomStart.copy( _zoomEnd );

   } else {

    _zoomStart.y += ( _zoomEnd.y - _zoomStart.y ) * this.dynamicDampingFactor;

   }

  }

 };

 this.panCamera = ( function () {

  var mouseChange = new THREE.Vector2(),
   objectUp = new THREE.Vector3(),
   pan = new THREE.Vector3();

  return function panCamera() {

   mouseChange.copy( _panEnd ).sub( _panStart );

   if ( mouseChange.lengthSq() ) {

    if ( _this.object.isOrthographicCamera ) {

     var scale_x = ( _this.object.right - _this.object.left ) / _this.object.zoom / _this.domElement.clientWidth;
     var scale_y = ( _this.object.top - _this.object.bottom ) / _this.object.zoom / _this.domElement.clientWidth;

     mouseChange.x *= scale_x;
     mouseChange.y *= scale_y;

    }

    mouseChange.multiplyScalar( _eye.length() * _this.panSpeed );

    pan.copy( _eye ).cross( _this.object.up ).setLength( mouseChange.x );
    pan.add( objectUp.copy( _this.object.up ).setLength( mouseChange.y ) );

    _this.object.position.add( pan );
    _this.target.add( pan );

    if ( _this.staticMoving ) {

     _panStart.copy( _panEnd );

    } else {

     _panStart.add( mouseChange.subVectors( _panEnd, _panStart ).multiplyScalar( _this.dynamicDampingFactor ) );

    }

   }

  };

 }() );

 this.checkDistances = function () {

  if ( ! _this.noZoom || ! _this.noPan ) {

   if ( _eye.lengthSq() > _this.maxDistance * _this.maxDistance ) {

    _this.object.position.addVectors( _this.target, _eye.setLength( _this.maxDistance ) );
    _zoomStart.copy( _zoomEnd );

   }

   if ( _eye.lengthSq() < _this.minDistance * _this.minDistance ) {

    _this.object.position.addVectors( _this.target, _eye.setLength( _this.minDistance ) );
    _zoomStart.copy( _zoomEnd );

   }

  }

 };

 this.update = function () {

  _eye.subVectors( _this.object.position, _this.target );

  if ( ! _this.noRotate ) {

   _this.rotateCamera();

  }

  if ( ! _this.noZoom ) {

   _this.zoomCamera();

  }

  if ( ! _this.noPan ) {

   _this.panCamera();

  }

  _this.object.position.addVectors( _this.target, _eye );

  if ( _this.object.isPerspectiveCamera ) {

   _this.checkDistances();

   _this.object.lookAt( _this.target );

   if ( lastPosition.distanceToSquared( _this.object.position ) > EPS ) {

    _this.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

    lastPosition.copy( _this.object.position );

   }

  } else if ( _this.object.isOrthographicCamera ) {

   _this.object.lookAt( _this.target );

   if ( lastPosition.distanceToSquared( _this.object.position ) > EPS || lastZoom !== _this.object.zoom ) {

    _this.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

    lastPosition.copy( _this.object.position );
    lastZoom = _this.object.zoom;

   }

  } else {

   console.warn( 'THREE.TrackballControls: Unsupported camera type' );

  }

 };

 this.reset = function () {

  _state = STATE.NONE;
  _keyState = STATE.NONE;

  _this.target.copy( _this.target0 );
  _this.object.position.copy( _this.position0 );
  _this.object.up.copy( _this.up0 );
  _this.object.zoom = _this.zoom0;

  _this.object.updateProjectionMatrix();

  _eye.subVectors( _this.object.position, _this.target );

  _this.object.lookAt( _this.target );

  _this.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

  lastPosition.copy( _this.object.position );
  lastZoom = _this.object.zoom;

 };

 // listeners

 function keydown( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  window.removeEventListener( 'keydown', keydown );

  if ( _keyState !== STATE.NONE ) {

   return;

  } else if ( event.keyCode === _this.keys[ STATE.ROTATE ] && ! _this.noRotate ) {

   _keyState = STATE.ROTATE;

  } else if ( event.keyCode === _this.keys[ STATE.ZOOM ] && ! _this.noZoom ) {

   _keyState = STATE.ZOOM;

  } else if ( event.keyCode === _this.keys[ STATE.PAN ] && ! _this.noPan ) {

   _keyState = STATE.PAN;

  }

 }

 function keyup() {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  _keyState = STATE.NONE;

  window.addEventListener( 'keydown', keydown, false );

 }

 function mousedown( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  if ( _state === STATE.NONE ) {

   switch ( event.button ) {

    case _this.mouseButtons.LEFT:
     _state = STATE.ROTATE;
     break;

    case _this.mouseButtons.MIDDLE:
     _state = STATE.ZOOM;
     break;

    case _this.mouseButtons.RIGHT:
     _state = STATE.PAN;
     break;

    default:
     _state = STATE.NONE;

   }

  }

  var state = ( _keyState !== STATE.NONE ) ? _keyState : _state;

  if ( state === STATE.ROTATE && ! _this.noRotate ) {

   _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );
   _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );

  } else if ( state === STATE.ZOOM && ! _this.noZoom ) {

   _zoomStart.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );
   _zoomEnd.copy( _zoomStart );

  } else if ( state === STATE.PAN && ! _this.noPan ) {

   _panStart.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );
   _panEnd.copy( _panStart );

  }

  document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', mousemove, false );
  document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', mouseup, false );

  _this.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

 }

 function mousemove( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  var state = ( _keyState !== STATE.NONE ) ? _keyState : _state;

  if ( state === STATE.ROTATE && ! _this.noRotate ) {

   _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
   _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );

  } else if ( state === STATE.ZOOM && ! _this.noZoom ) {

   _zoomEnd.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );

  } else if ( state === STATE.PAN && ! _this.noPan ) {

   _panEnd.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );

  }

 }

 function mouseup( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  _state = STATE.NONE;

  document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', mousemove );
  document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', mouseup );
  _this.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

 }

 function mousewheel( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  if ( _this.noZoom === true ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  switch ( event.deltaMode ) {

   case 2:
    // Zoom in pages
    _zoomStart.y -= event.deltaY * 0.025;
    break;

   case 1:
    // Zoom in lines
    _zoomStart.y -= event.deltaY * 0.01;
    break;

   default:
    // undefined, 0, assume pixels
    _zoomStart.y -= event.deltaY * 0.00025;
    break;

  }

  _this.dispatchEvent( startEvent );
  _this.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

 }

 function touchstart( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();

  switch ( event.touches.length ) {

   case 1:
    _state = STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE;
    _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY ) );
    _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
    break;

   default: // 2 or more
    _state = STATE.TOUCH_ZOOM_PAN;
    var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
    var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;
    _touchZoomDistanceEnd = _touchZoomDistanceStart = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

    var x = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX + event.touches[ 1 ].pageX ) / 2;
    var y = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageY + event.touches[ 1 ].pageY ) / 2;
    _panStart.copy( getMouseOnScreen( x, y ) );
    _panEnd.copy( _panStart );
    break;

  }

  _this.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

 }

 function touchmove( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  switch ( event.touches.length ) {

   case 1:
    _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
    _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY ) );
    break;

   default: // 2 or more
    var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
    var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;
    _touchZoomDistanceEnd = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

    var x = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX + event.touches[ 1 ].pageX ) / 2;
    var y = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageY + event.touches[ 1 ].pageY ) / 2;
    _panEnd.copy( getMouseOnScreen( x, y ) );
    break;

  }

 }

 function touchend( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  switch ( event.touches.length ) {

   case 0:
    _state = STATE.NONE;
    break;

   case 1:
    _state = STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE;
    _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY ) );
    _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
    break;

  }

  _this.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

 }

 function contextmenu( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();

 }

 this.dispose = function () {

  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'contextmenu', contextmenu, false );
  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', mousedown, false );
  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'wheel', mousewheel, false );

  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchstart', touchstart, false );
  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchend', touchend, false );
  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchmove', touchmove, false );

  document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', mousemove, false );
  document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', mouseup, false );

  window.removeEventListener( 'keydown', keydown, false );
  window.removeEventListener( 'keyup', keyup, false );

 };

 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', contextmenu, false );
 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', mousedown, false );
 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'wheel', mousewheel, false );

 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchstart', touchstart, false );
 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchend', touchend, false );
 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchmove', touchmove, false );

 window.addEventListener( 'keydown', keydown, false );
 window.addEventListener( 'keyup', keyup, false );

 this.handleResize();

 // force an update at start
 this.update();

};

TrackballControls.prototype = Object.create( THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype );
TrackballControls.prototype.constructor = TrackballControls;

//////////////////////////// END OF TRACKBALL SOURCE CODE ////////////////////////////

// Boilerplate Three setup
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("canvas")});
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 20;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const geometry = new THREE.TorusBufferGeometry(8, 3, 16, 32);
const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

// Now we can use the controls as expected
const controls = new TrackballControls(camera , renderer.domElement );
controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
controls.panSpeed = 0.8;

function resize() {
  var width = renderer.domElement.clientWidth;
  var height = renderer.domElement.clientHeight;
  if (renderer.domElement.width !== width || renderer.domElement.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function animate(time) {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

resize();
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I ended up finding a way to work around the issue by serving my existing pages using NanoHTTPD web server and then loading them into the WebView from there. However I do think refactoriong the code this way could help work around the issue from the Javascript side and I appreciate you taking the time to make the sample code and explain the changes. I am awarding you the bounty. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`TrackballControls.js` is not an ES6 module, and does not export the `TrackballControls` constructor function. `TrackballControls` is attached to `THREE`.
`ts` is likely just an empty object, and `ts.TrackballControls` is undefined.
Define `controls` like the following instead.

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera , renderer.domElement);
```

My answer is based on this [`TrackballControls.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js) on Github.